# How to search in files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am coming from Sublime Text 2, where I can open a workspace (a directory with all the source files). There is an option "find in files" (ctrl+shift+f) that searches for an expression in all the files from that directory and subdirectories. Now, in Visual Studio Code, there is such an option with the same shortcut as Sublime, but it only searches in the files that are opened in a tab, not all actual files in the directory currently opened. Is there a way to do this with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: there is a search icon in the shape of a magnifying glass that will do this. I don't put this as an answer as it's not keyboard based

Comment: That icon is the same option as "ctrl+shift+f", but it only searches within files that are already opened in tabs, not all files, even though there is a couple of textboxes to enter filespecs to include or exclude.

Comment: not in my version of vscode. Did you change any settings perhaps?

Comment: I am using 1.14.2. I only added two new specifications to search.exclude, but removing them does not change the behavior.

Comment: I just noticed it: when using it with typescript it works fine, but with C++ (extension C/C++ installed) it behaves like that.

Comment: interesting - looks like a bug then.

Answer (score 1):

"CTRL+SHIFT+F" does only search on open files. What you need to do is open up the explorer "CTRL+SHIFT+E", right click on the folder you're attempting to search under, and select "Find in Folder...".

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43651677/6395820