# How to search for just a specific file type in Visual Studio code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, search, file-type

In Visual Studio code, how do I search for just a specific file type (i.e. `*.css` or `*.ts`)?

PS: I'm talking about the global search (Ctrl+Shift+F in Windows)

I'm already using the "files to include" as a folder filter. So currently it has something like `./src/app`.

Comment: @OcelotXL Ctrl + Shift + F in Visual Studio *Code* in Windows (as opposed to Visual Studio Code in Mac or Visual Studio Code in Linux). Just to be clear!

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Click the ellipses on the bottom right to display the "files to include" field.

You can specify a particular type with "*.filetype".

E.g.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ok, sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm already using the "files to include" as a folder filter. So currently it has something like "./src/app"

Comment: Update: just realised I can simply do "./src/app/*.ts" :D Thanks! :)

Comment: To group filters, you can use {}.. Like: {./src/app, *.ts}

Comment: Ahh, this is great! If you want to search for a test file with varying extensions you can do: `*.test*`. We have tests with anthing from `.test.tsx` to `.test.js`...

Comment: weird. I don't have the ellipses (three little dots) in that search dialog. I'm on a mac too.

Comment: I shouldn't need to click a dropdown to filter by filetype. I should be a matter of typing "`foobar type:csv`"

Comment: Thanks. How could i have missed that?

Comment: how do I search for all files of that file type? when I leave the search blank it doesn't search...

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Asking the real questions! This is my issue, also. I want to step through every `*.js` file in my folder. I don't want to and cannot search for a certain content.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler my suggestion, search with linux (if on windows use WSL with mnt/c/)

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Just enable regular expressions and type in `.` which will match any character.

Comment: Not sure if you can do "None" ?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Entering one space in the search bar ran the query and returned all the files with the extension I wanted. I suppose if a file with the desired extension didn't have a space that it wouldn't be included, but I imagine pretty much any file you're interested in will have at least one space

Answer (score 132):

You can do this.

```
./src/app/**/*.ts
```

other glob syntax

- `*` to match one or more characters in a path segment
- `?` to match on one character in a path segment
- `**` to match any number of path segments, including none
- `{}` to group conditions (for example {**/*.html,**/*.txt} matches
  all HTML and text files)
- `[]` to declare a range of characters to match (example.[0-9] to
  match on example.0, example.1, …)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Could you provide the source link, please? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @sdlins, you can find it on vscode doc somewhere here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs

Comment: FWIW the braces aren't necessary to group a file type only query, and make sure to include a comma to separate file types, e.g. `*.css, *.ts, *.js, *.html`

Comment: @sdlins Here's the exact source link in the VS Code docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options

Comment: I was looking for the group conditions. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This should be the approved answer. It actually provides a way to search both "within a specific folder" and "by filetype".

Comment: How to trigger the search then? It does not seem to work, unless I additionally use some phrase to search in the files.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the file search option (ctrl+p), then copy the subfolder relative path in the project, followed by the pattern to search the files. For example:

```
subfolder_path/*.hpp
```

In the provided list, you can open each one by using the right click ... unfortunatelly I did not find a way to store the list somehow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).