# How to search vscode by specific file type only not folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

In using file filter in VSCode [How to search for just a specific file type in Visual Studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589598/how-to-search-for-just-a-specific-file-type-in-visual-studio-code) does in fact include folder

*.py will also include folders myfolder.py : is it possible to exclude folders ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I choose folders to be ignored during search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971600/how-can-i-choose-folders-to-be-ignored-during-search)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me exactly what you are trying to do, but if you want to **include** `*.py` files but **exclude** folders like `something.py` this seems to work:

files to include: `*.py`

files to exclude: `*.py/*`

Using that you will **not** get search hits from `folder.py/file.py`

but you **will** from `anotherFile.py` that is not in the `folder.py`.