# Regular expression to find empty functions

Tags: php, regex

I would like to use a regular expression that finds only functions that are empty in php files

For example

```
function name_not_important()
{
}
```

Comment: @VishalSingh It didn't work here, I even tested it on this site https://regex101.com/r/6RsBEK/1/

Comment: Your function contains the word test it's not empty.

Comment: `function [a-z]\w*\(\)\s*\{\s*\}`

Comment: @VishalSingh Thank you very much, it worked, now I also wanted you to find all these functions that were inside files that ended with the name pesq.class.php, could you help me?

Comment: Just a note that if you're using PhpStorm, you can use structural search to easily find empty functions (no need for any regex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex can be `function\s[^\(]+\([^)]*\)(\n)*{(\n)*}`

**From https://regex101.com/:**

> - function matches the characters function literally (case sensitive) \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>   Match a single character not present in the list below [^(]
>
> - matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) ( matches the
>   character ( literally (case sensitive) ( matches the character (
>   literally (case sensitive) Match a single character not present in the
>   list below [^)]
>
> - matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) ) matches the
>   character ) literally (case sensitive) ) matches the character )
>   literally (case sensitive) 1st Capturing Group (\n)*
> - matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) A repeated capturing
>   group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group
>   around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a
>   non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data \n
>   matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10) { matches the
>   character { literally (case sensitive) 2nd Capturing Group (\n)*
> - matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) A repeated capturing
>   group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group
>   around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a
>   non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data \n
>   matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10) } matches the
>   character } literally (case sensitive) Global pattern flags g
>   modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match) m
>   modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each
>   line (not only begin/end of string)

**Note:** This regex assumes that indentation of braces are in alignment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now could you tell me how do I find all these empty functions that are in php files that end with the name pesq.class.php?

Comment: @Yuri007 Say we found, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I will replace the code of all occurrences found, for that I will use the replace of visual studio code

Comment: @Yuri007 Ok, would you mind shifting pesq.class.php files to a different folder and then applying this search?

Comment: It gets complicated, because there are many files, thousands in various folders

Comment: @Yuri007 This looks like a task. You can write a php script to recursively iterate files/folders, check the file names, get their content and then apply this search and use preg_replace to replace it with your code.

Comment: @Yuri007 You can also post this as a separate question with your attempt.

Comment: Um, it's a good idea, I thought you could do this with grep or something

Comment: How do I include in the regular expression * .pesq.class.php? So I try here in visual studio code, it scans all directories

Comment: @Yuri007 Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589598/how-to-search-for-just-a-specific-file-type-in-visual-studio-code ?

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot, now just to finish, I have the following function function SC_carga_evt_jquery (), this is the only empty function that I don't want to find, can I add this to the regex?

Comment: @Yuri007 Is this function inside an interface or a class? If it's inside a class, these empty functions won't make a difference with or without existence