# In vs code how do i search files ending with .html in a specific folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I'd like to be able to find files ending with .html in a specific folder.

What does work is if i do `*.html`  but not when i do `folder/*.html`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search for just a specific file type in Visual Studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589598/how-to-search-for-just-a-specific-file-type-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: It looks like your `Search only in Open Editors` icon is enabled.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt thank you i found this commenthttps://stackoverflow.com/a/56664405/5517161

Comment: I solved it with the keyword: `./src/app/components/**/*.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book on the right side is to *search only in open editors*.

In this probably what void your search unless you opened matching files.