# VS Code - Search for text in all only c++ (.cpp) and header (.h) files in a directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Is there a way to search for a text in only CPP and header files in a directory using VS Code?**

I.e., if I press "Ctrl+Shift+F" and search for a text, it will search in all the files including README and other files also in the current directory and return the files that matched. Basically I want to search for a text only in C++ (.cpp) and header (.h) files.

There is a similar question - "[VS Code - Search for text in all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572974/vs-code-search-for-text-in-all-files-in-a-directory#)". It does not help because it will search in all files ignoring the extension of the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open the file filter with the ellipsis, and seperate file extensions to filter with a comma:

[image]

This will search only `.cpp` and `.h` files.